# Named Credential with Basic Authorization Token, Username and Password details

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials, externalcredentials

I am trying to callout to an external application APIs to fetch data into Salesforce.

That external application has Auth token URL which will need below details to share Access token (bearer) to be supplied to get the resource on resource URL. And I dont have client ID or Client Secret.
So as a **step 1** am hitting to the AUTH URL with these details to get Bearer token

```
Auth URL xyz.com/oauth/token
Authorization Basic xxxx
Content Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Grant Type  
Username xxxx
Password xxxx
```

Step2: Supplying the bearer token received from step1 to the header of resource URL

```
resourceRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
```

I am able to do call out by giving all these details directly in the APEX program. I want to achieve the same with Named Credentials but not able to succeed.When checked on adding External credentials, I didnt understand which option to use in this case. Can you please share some insights on how Named credentials can be used to achieve this use case.

Comment: The option to use depends on grant type supported by your service, an important detail you left out of your question. The request signature matches Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) grant type. Since ROPC is highly unsecure for many use cases, the [industry voted to outlaw it](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-24.html#name-resource-owner-password-cre). For this and other reasons, Named/Ext Credentials do not support ROPC out of the box.

Comment: ok got it. Is there any workaround solutions to use this with Named Credentials?

Comment: Do a search, this question has been asked before